# How to group header files in header subfolders under the general header files folder using Cmake

Tags: visual-c++, file, header, cmake

Hi I am building Cmake based build system. 
I would like to group header files in folders (VC++ can do it) under the general folder Header Files.
Similar, I would like to group the corresponding `.cpp` files in folders under the Source Files directory.
Unfortunately I could not find any instructions of how to do it.

Please help.

Dimitre

Answer (score 0):

You should give a look at CMake [source_group](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3asource_group) command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [source_group](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/source_group.html). Here's a concrete example.

Suppose you have a directory structure like:

```
|-include
    | some.h
    |-sub
       | someother.h 
|-src
   | some.cpp
   |-sub
      |-someother.cpp
```

Collect the files (some people - including the documentation - discourages use of GLOB, but I leave that to you, you can list of them one by if you want to, though I find GLOB is just fine many times):

```
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/*.h")
file(GLOB HEADER_FILES_SUB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/sub/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/*.h")
file(GLOB SOURCE_FILES_SUB "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src/sub/*.h")

# Setup your library or executable:
add_library(MY_LIB ${HEADER_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES_SUB}
                   ${SOURCE_FILES} ${SOURCE_FILES_SUB})

# Here's the important part ("Header Files" and "Source Files" are literals.)
source_group("Header Files\\sub" ${HEADER_FILES_SUB})
source_group("Source Files\\sub" ${SOURCE_FILES_SUB})
```